# Scripts quits after launching Popen command

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
  while True:  
      command = 'cmd /c start chrome http://google.com'
      subprocess.Popen(command)
      time.sleep(120)
```

When i try to launch the browser chrome using this code in python, the browser launches but after that my script quits. Is there a way to launch the browser and move on to process next block of codes.

I tried changin`/c` to `/K` and using `subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).wait()` but in this case it will neither quit nor process the next block of codes

Comment: Does your script quit silently, or is there an error message/stack trace?

Comment: Is `chrome` in your PATH? You probably need to supply the full path to the chrome executable

Comment: quits silently, chrome is in the PATH. Hmm seems like the issue was `wait()`.it can process the next block of code if i remove that and using `/K`

Comment: Your existing code works for me here on Windows XP

Answer (score 3):

Wait () will wait for the launched program to terminate.
Without the wait your script will continue after launching

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to wait(). if wait() is removed ,the script will continue